# How can I hide or remove ui components and move the other to occupy the space of the hidden or deleted?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I have a view in my storyboard with labels, textfield, and buttons, I want that when I clicked in a button some textfields and labels dissapear, in Swift I can use.

```
self.btnLoginFB.hidden = true
self.btnLoginFB.removeFromSuperview()
```

but if I hide the field the space go on being occupied and if I try to remove, all the another components go to another space outside the storyboard.

Please I need help to make that, in html is enough with hide the div but in the storyboard I don't know :(

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 9 then you may be able to use UIStackViews; they automatically adjust when an element is hidden, otherwise you need to manipulate your constraints so that the hidden item has a zero height

Comment: are you working with auto layout?

Comment: Thanks, using UIStackView it was fixed. Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Autolayout, hiding the field will, as you noticed, not fill the space it was in. That space stays unoccupied. Removing from superview will cause all sorts of wonky things to happen.

Here's how I accomplish this task, setup the view you want to fill the space with Autolayout correctly (i.e., if View A is above View B, set View B's top to be x margin away from View A's bottom.) Then you can either hide the view or not (I usually do for sanity's sake), and the most important part is setting the height of View A to be 0. I usually do this by manipulating the constant on View A's height constraint, but you can also explicitly change the height to 0, as long as your height goes to 0.

If you set up Autolayout properly, this will correctly move any views above or below to fill the space, depending how you related your views to one another. Let me know if you have any questions.

Edit: So I'll usually keep a property around for my height constraint if I know I'm going to be hiding a constraint, so what I'll usually do is something like this (for hiding view A):

```
viewA.hidden = YES;
heightConstraint.constant = 0;
[viewA setNeedsDisplay];
```

To change the height only:

```
viewA.hidden = YES;
CGRect newFrame = viewA.frame;
newFrame.size.height = 0;
viewA.frame = newFrame;
[viewA setNeedsDisplay];
```

The call to `setNeedsDisplay` may be extraneous, but I'm not actually building this out so I'm not sure, I think you need it in scenario 1 and don't need it in scenario 2.

Also, for these to work out of the box like this, you need to make sure View B is set to be pinned to either View A's top or bottom edge, that way it will automatically fill the space left behind. If you're not using Autolayout, you'll need to calculate the correct frame for View B yourself and set it after hiding View A.

Comment: Please can you show me one example, because I am trying you said and it does not work.

Comment: I just updated my answer to include some code snippets of both ways. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: You can also put a call to `setNeedsLayout` in a UIView animation block to animate the change

Comment: A little bit of visual flair can go a long way with users!